# Keyframe animation not running - what is missing?

Tags: css

I thought I'd try out a basic bouncing icon, but I'm not seeing any bounce, and I'm stumpted as to why (are there any features in chrome/FF dev tools specifically for css animations?). I've declared keyframes for each browser prefix, and done:

```
animation: bounce 2s infinite;
-webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
-moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
-o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
```

What else am I missing? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p0n5dL59/

Comment: The animation itself has *nothing* which alters the original element.... so what is supposed to animate? In order for an animation to be *seen* the css must change *something* - color, size, position, etc. You've got none of that.

Comment: Oh, I see! Well that's absent-minded of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation properties you defined in your `@keyframes` need to go on the element the animation applies to instead. Then the `@keyframes` needs to define what happens in the animation, like

```
@keyframes animation-name {
  to {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Here's a reference https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: `@keyframes bounce {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: bounce;
}` is just a bunch of animation properties. Those belong under the element you're applying the animation to. Instead, this `@keyframes` CSS should contain the things you want the animation to do, like `0% { top: -5px; } 50% { top: 0; } 100% { top: -5px; }` or whatever will make a "bounce" effect.